# Can Ruby/Rails create objects when passed a JSON containing the parameters and other key-values?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does Ruby/Rails have any magic logic that can create an object (`Customer.create(...)`) from a JSON or YAML with the defined parameters, along with extraneous key-values in said file?

The context of the problem is ingesting/seeding a table `Customer` in a Rails app from a bulk JSON file. The model contains only pertinent information but will evolve to include other information (like "birth-date", "gender").

(And for further but unnecessary context -- one view will display information about all 'Customer' when passed a list of customer names or IDs.)

For instance given a model,

```
class Customer:
  def initialize(first, last, age)
      @cust_first = first
      @cust_last = last
      @cust_age = age
  end
  ...
end
```

...is there a mechanic where I can just feed a huge JSON, and it will feed it in? That way as the model `Customer` transforms, the ingestion script does not need to be changed?

```rb
# [{'First':'John','Last':'Smith','Age':'50','Gender':'M','ActiveSub':'N'...},{...},...]
bulk_data = JSON.parse(File.read('tmp/customers-20221001.json'))

bulk_data.each do |customer_json|
  temp = Customer.new(customer_json) # <-- syntax in question
  temp.save
end
```

Also interested in why this idea might be unsafe, messy, etc.

Comment: Change `class Customer:` to `class Customer`.

Comment: It not unsafe or messy - its just unrealistic to think that there is some tool that will fit your exact buisness logic that would take less time to setup then just doing what is a very easy job - normalizing your inputs.

Comment: Have you checked `from_json` method https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/from_json You should probably dive into serialization / deserialization

Comment: @Maxence , I didn't, thanks. Have trouble finding the write words to search sometimes. Thanks!